# Audio player randomly mutes itself on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, audio

I have a web app built with ReactJS, uses react-h5-audio-player for audio.

Now, the app works perfectly on PC and Android, but on iOS the audio randomly mutes itself. It usually happens at the start of the song, maybe plays for like up to 10 seconds then loses audio or on song change. Sometimes you can play like 5 songs before this happens, sometimes 10 (it is random). You can see from the progress bar that the audio is still playing from app and from the iOS UI itself (when you put the browser in background and check notifications panel/home screen). Now, when I move the progress bar on iOS UI to some random part the audio comes back.

I tried many different settings on my iPhone, including resetting all settings, but nothing seems to work, tried restarting iPhone as well. The iPhone is on the latest iOS, last year model (14). Also, as I said the app works perfectly on Android and PC.

Does anyone have any ideas how could I fix this, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you upload that specific code of player here so finding out  what's the root of the problem.

Best